# Test Classes: MIXED_DML_OPERATION

Tags: process-builder, error, dml, failing-tests

Via Process Builder, Is there anything I can do in my process that could stop this from occurring?

**Error Message**:

```
System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): EmailMessage, original object: User:
```

Comment: can you add code of test class as well?

Comment: I don't want to change the test class code.

Is there anything criteria-wise or scheduled-action wise that would stop this error from occuring?